# How to resolve "Storage Engine Operation Failed" with Microsoft.Sync?

Tags: c#, desktop-application, microsoft-sync-framework, sql-server-2014-express

I have developed a synchronization software that will sync Databases and Directories using Microsoft Sync Framework 2.1.

After a while a client using the application gets this error :

> A storage engine operation failed with error code 25104 (HRESULT = 0x80004005, Source IID = {0C733A63-2A1C-11CE-ADE5-00AA0044773D}, Parameters=(4001, 0, 0, , , ,)).

I tried to track the error within my code but with no success.

The error occurs when the SyncOchestrator begins Synchronization. And from the stacktrace I got :

> at Microsoft.Synchronization.Files.FileSyncProvider...ctor()

Here is some of my coding :

```
 try
        {
            // Set options for the sync operation
            FileSyncOptions options = FileSyncOptions.ExplicitDetectChanges |
                     FileSyncOptions.RecycleDeletedFiles | FileSyncOptions.RecyclePreviousFileOnUpdates | FileSyncOptions.RecycleConflictLoserFiles;

            FileSyncScopeFilter filter = new FileSyncScopeFilter();
            filter.FileNameExcludes.Add("*.lnk"); // Exclude all *.lnk files
            filter.FileNameExcludes.Add("*.mdf"); // Exclude all *.mdf files
            filter.FileNameExcludes.Add("*.ldf"); // Exclude all *.ldf files
            filter.FileNameExcludes.Add("*.MDF"); // Exclude all *.MDF files
            filter.FileNameExcludes.Add("*.LDF"); // Exclude all *.LDF files
            filter.FileNameExcludes.Add("*.tdms_index"); // Exclude all *.tdms_index files

            Thread.Sleep(50);
            // Synchronization of 2 Folders
            FileSyncProvider providerA = new FileSyncProvider(Guid.NewGuid(), replica1RootPath, filter, options);
            FileSyncProvider providerB = new FileSyncProvider(Guid.NewGuid(), replica2RootPath, filter, options);
            providerA.DetectChanges();
            providerB.DetectChanges();

            Thread.Sleep(50);
            SyncOrchestrator agent = new SyncOrchestrator();
            agent.LocalProvider = providerA;
            agent.RemoteProvider = providerB;
            agent.Direction = SyncDirectionOrder.Upload;
            MessageBox.Show("Let's SYNC");
            agent.Synchronize(); // The error happens here

            Thread.Sleep(50);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
            MessageBox.Show(e.StackTrace);
        }
```

Can you please help me with this? I'm getting frustrated and I don't know where should I look! The code worked perfectly for one year.

For more information :

- The end user has all the required access rights for the folders.
- The file server has plenty of free space to write.

I'm on C#, Microsoft.Synchronization 2.1, .Net 4, Visual Studio 2015.

Thank you very much for any suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured out the solution. It happened that the Metadata file was too big / corrupted. So to solve my problem I fragmented the synchronization and selected all the subfolders one by one instead of selecting just one folder with 260 Go of files.

```
foreach (string dep in Directory.GetDirectories(plantFolder1)) // different departements
                            {
                                string depFolder1 = plantFolder1 + dep.Remove(0, plantFolder1.Length);
                                string depFolder2 = depFolder1.Replace(subReplica1, subReplica2); ;

                                Thread.Sleep(50);
                                // Synchronization of 2 Folders
                                FileSyncProvider providerA = new FileSyncProvider(Guid.NewGuid(), depFolder1, filter, options);

                                bool exists = Directory.Exists(depFolder2);
                                if (!exists)
                                    Directory.CreateDirectory(depFolder2);

                                FileSyncProvider providerB = new FileSyncProvider(Guid.NewGuid(), depFolder2, filter, options);
                                providerA.DetectChanges();
                                providerB.DetectChanges();

                                Thread.Sleep(50);
                                SyncOrchestrator agent = new SyncOrchestrator();
                                agent.LocalProvider = providerA;
                                agent.RemoteProvider = providerB;
                                agent.Direction = SyncDirectionOrder.Upload;
                                agent.Synchronize();
                                Thread.Sleep(50);
                            }
```

That's the solution for my problem. I hope this will help you folks.

Thanks.